# How can I pull out only records that have FAIL against them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this will be quite simple for some one clued up in SQL but I think it needs a sub query or something. I have a table which basically has a load of order numbers in it and a reply column from an XML API. Either FAIL or SUCCESS.

A brand new row is inserted into the DB after every request. So there may be 5 FAILS for one order number, and on the 6th attempt a record is inserted saying SUCCESS.

How can I put out order numbers that ONLY have a FAIL status next to them?

This will allow me to figure out what records need looking into that continuously fail in the API request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, by grouping your orders with primary key (order_id)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(status) as status_combined, order_id
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY order_id  
) AS order_tmp
WHERE status_combined NOT LIKE '%SUCCESS%'
```

**`Edit`** (As per asker comments)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(status) as status_combined, order_id
    FROM orders 
    JOIN certificates ON certificates.Ordernumber = orders.OrderNumber
    GROUP BY order_id  
) AS order_tmp
WHERE status_combined NOT LIKE '%SUCCESS%'
```

please make sure you need to join based on "Ordernumber" or "order_id"

Comment: This is working - where would I put in a join to my main orders table which has an OrderStatus column with either cancelled or booking in? I would like to filter out any order numbers that are cancelled in the other order table! Thanks

Comment: You can put all the join tables in the query inside paranthesis, and all the statuses which you want to ignore you can put additional condition for e.g. WHERE status_combined NOT LIKE '%SUCCESS%' AND WHERE status_combined NOT LIKE '%CANCELLED%' etc.

Comment: I relooked at this today - can you update your original answer please as I am still struggling with the JOIN! I need to add this is some how: JOIN certificates ON certificates.Ordernumber = orders.OrderNumber

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select m.*
from Main m
join Transactiontable tt
on m.orderid = tt.orderid
group by tt.status , m.orderid
having count(case when tt.status = "failed") = count(tt.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple sql query using a where clause:

```
select * 
from some_table 
where Column_From_some_table_has_value = your_particular_value
```

thats enough.

You can have a look at [How to use where clause in sql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the cleanest way to do it:

```
select *
from mytable
where id in (
    select id
    from mytable
    group by id
    having sum(status = 'SUCCESS') = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of @Minesh's answer because it uses both an aggregate function and the `LIKE` operator.  Both of those can cause performance issues since there won't be any indexes to help the query out with the difficult part of the work.  The `LIKE` clause particularly is a lot of work for the database since it will need to scan every result.

I'm more familiar with SQL Server, but this should work well for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (
        SELECT OrderNumber
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Status = 'SUCCESS')
    AND OrderNumber NOT IN (
        SELECT OrderNumber
        FROM Certificates
        WHERE OrderStatus = 'CANCELLED')
```